# Why does my kernel.log file report 'Link Training Error' and 'Failed to check link status'?

Tags: kernel, pci

Every 3 to 5 seconds I get the following output in kernel.log file. How do you fix this?

```
Oct 28 00:04:30 host kernel: [57192.331327] pciehp 0000:00:1c.4:pcie04: Link Training Error occurs 
Oct 28 00:04:30 host kernel: [57192.331331] pciehp 0000:00:1c.4:pcie04: Failed to check link status
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your machine doesn't support PCI-E hotplugging.

Assuming you have an eeepc, read [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/557048), particularly [Post 15](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/557048/comments/15):

> Well, there are 3 different issues with the 1005PE model, which are related.
>
> First, Win7 compatible bios, check if the eeepc-laptop module is loaded:
>   `lsmod | grep eee`
>   If not, you'll need this kernel parameter:
>   `acpi_osi=Linux`
>
> Second, to fix the brightness, another parameter:
>   `acpi_backlight=vendor`
>
> Finally, the actual bug, as described in acpi4asus git:
>   http://git.iksaif.net/?p=acpi4asus.git;a=commit;h=ced69c59811f05b2f8378467cbb82ac6ed3c6a5a
>
> To work around the problem, disable hotplugging with this parameter:
>   `eeepc_laptop.hotplug_disabled=1`
>
> Summarizing, add the needed parameters to your Grub, see below, and update:
>   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor eeepc_laptop.hotplug_disabled=1"`